# Connecting GND on secondary side to protective ground

Tags: power-supply, filter, earth, floating

We have a battery powered equipment which mainly consists of a temperature sensor connected to a microcontroller via a filter. In addition to battery power we have now added the possibility to use a common 9V plug in DC power supply. When using this power supply the mesaured temperature fluctuates a lot which is a large problem. The whole device is of cause floating compared to earth and it seems to be large potentials (50 Hz) between the device and earth.

I have tried to filter all internal supply voltages without any success.

Between the sensor and the microcontroller is a common mode filter and an RC-filter. I could stabilize the temperature by increasing capacitor C1 to 1 uF but this will influence the temperature signal too much. The temperature decreases approximately exponentially with up to 200-300 degrees Celsius/second.

Another way to make the temperature reading stable is to connect system ground to protective earth which I have tried. Are there any disadvantages to do that? The best would be a power supply with secondary ground connected to earth but it seems that this is almost possible to find, at least in EU. Isn't that allowed. And the customer wants that almost any 9V plug in power supply could be used which is understandable.

Any advice?
See picture. Everything inside the red rectangle is floating regarding to earth. The power supply is connected with a 5.5/2.5 mm DC plug.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! What’s the CM chokes role on the output? What are your possibilities to use your secondary negative (“ground”) as reference for your external sensor instead of earth?

Comment: You could even ground through a large resistor if the problem is 50 Hz. You should provide details on how the line is read by the "system" (e.g. instrum. amplifier) and which type of 9V supply we are speaking of. To tackle the noise source you should measure its waveform and try to identify components and characteristics that can be led back to one of your subsystems/devices or mains/environment.

Comment: Secondary ground to PE bonding is actually *required* in EU for control systems under the machinery directive (the idea being to blow a fuse if something leaks to the chassis). How is the sensor communicating back? A current loop of some kind? it seems that there is some other path to ground to make that kind of interference

Comment: Ground is used as reference for the sensor. The sensor is a thermocouple connected to an A/D converter via a AD627 instrumentation amplifier.

Comment: A large resistor or a capacitor between secondary ground and PE would probably solve the problem. The customer prefer to use an ordinary plug-in DC power supply like  Meanwell GSM12E09-P1J or Cui SDI36-9-U-P5 or similar that can easily be bought by the end user. Meanwell has a few that has secondary ground connected to PE but they are not available in EU according to Mouser.